# HIve: Using Cast with COALESCE and aliasing it

Tags: hive, group-by, hiveql

For a given use case. I'm trying to use COALESCE with CAST. Tried couple of sources online but none of them was helpful (may be due to to my limited knowledge).

I tried the following query for getting the result via aliasing COALESCE

```
SELECT
    S.id,
    S.subj_cd,
    S.wrk_cd,
    COALESCE(S.ord_cnt,0) AS order,
    COALESCE(M.trans_cnt,0) AS trans
FROM
    DB_USER.ORD_CNT S
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB_USER.TRANS_CNT M ON
    (S.id = M.id
    AND S.subj_cd = M.subj_cd
    AND S.wrk_cd = M.wrk_cd
WHERE   S.id=111111
GROUP BY
    S.id,
    S.subj_cd,
    S.wrk_cd,
    order,
    trans
```

but this is not working. Getting an error:
    `Invalid column reference 'ord_cnt'`

Then tried the following:

```
SELECT
    S.id,
    S.subj_cd,
    S.wrk_cd,
    CAST(COALESCE(S.ord_cnt,0)) AS order,
    COALESCE(M.trans_cnt,0) AS trans
FROM
    DB_USER.ORD_CNT S
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB_USER.TRANS_CNT M ON
    (S.id = M.id
    AND S.subj_cd = M.subj_cd
    AND S.wrk_cd = M.wrk_cd
WHERE   S.id=111111
GROUP BY
    S.id,
    S.subj_cd,
    S.wrk_cd,
    order,
    trans
```

but then this also failed with an error:
`Invalid table alias or column reference 'order':`

It's pretty simple and silly of me. But have spent couple of hours to figure it out but not getting anywhere. Any direction to move ahead will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:

```
SELECT
    S.id,
    S.subj_cd,
    S.wrk_cd,
    COALESCE(S.ord_cnt,0) AS `order`,
    COALESCE(M.trans_cnt,0) AS trans
FROM
    DB_USER.ORD_CNT S
LEFT OUTER JOIN DB_USER.TRANS_CNT M ON
    S.id = M.id
    AND S.subj_cd = M.subj_cd
    AND S.wrk_cd = M.wrk_cd
WHERE   S.id=111111
GROUP BY
    S.id,
    S.subj_cd,
    S.wrk_cd,
    COALESCE(S.ord_cnt,0),  --use un-aliased columns in the group by
    COALESCE(M.trans_cnt,0) --use un-aliased columns in the group by
```